# Adding icon on WPF XAML window causes error/crash VS2012

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I found a bug in WPF XAML when specifying an icon for a XAML Window, trying to run the program generates an error message on the line:

```
 System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Me, resourceLocater)
```

XamlParseException occurred

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '100'.

I've set the icon to `Always Create` on the `Copy To Output Directory` with no luck.
I changed the icon from `Resource` to `EmbeddedResource`  - no luck there either.
I added it to the `Resources` for the project - still no luck.
I've verified the file and its location 100%.
The XAML of the window is correct, the name is correct, the path is correct.

```
Icon="Resources/VisualizerIcon.ico"
```

Stumped - online forums say to Copy to output Directory is the solution, but, after building the solution, only the Folder is copied over (even though I explicitly set the ICO file to be copied).

Anyone?

Comment: NOTE: I cleaned the project and the ICO file is now showing up in the BIN folder, but still get same error as above.

Comment: Did you look at : [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.loadcomponent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: wasn't really sure how to use the info there, but found, if I name the window (which wasn't named before) and assign the icon in the _Loaded evebt, it works fine. The problem is that the icon property is looking for an BitmapSource, not a Bitmap. So I had to convert the Bitmap to a Bitmapsource to use it.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to set the build action for the actual image/icon to Resource as shown in the properties window..

[image]

I know it's an old post, just wanted to share a dummy error..

Comment: is right! Whyever Resources are not set to be built as Resources!? The WPF way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the project setting to set it up (right click on your project, then select 'Properties')

As in this screenshot:
[image]

I find it is simpler, no code needed, and it works ...

Comment: That was the first thing I tried (I added the ico and another embedded resource using the technique you show above), but it still crashed with the same error message. Go figure.

Comment: that's weird ... you sure you had the type ok? and did the usual clean, rebuild, pray to the wooden chicken gods that it'll build ok?

Comment: There could be something I missed, this is my first foray into WPF.

Comment: Welcome to the WPF wagon then ... it's a nice ride once you get the horses in the right direction. Have a quick test with a new solution. Just put a label, and try to see if you can set the Icon through the setup. If yes, something is messed in your project. If not, dang, something weird is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Resources compile property to Resources. then use

```
    <Image width="80" Height="80" Source="Resources/my_image.png"/>
```

or icon for window

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication" x:Name="Main_Window" x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Icon="Resources/icon.ico">
```

Comment: This only works because you're referencing an ICO file directly, if you replaced that with `{StaticResource}` binding to the `<Image>` resource you'd get an exception like "System.Windows.Image' is not valid for property 'Icon'."

Answer (score 1):

Try check for the inner exception. If the call site looks like:

> at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CriticalCopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect, IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
>     at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CriticalCopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect, System.Array, Int32, Int32)
>     at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect, System.Array, Int32, Int32)
>     at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CopyPixels(System.Array, Int32, Int32)
>     at MS.Internal.AppModel.IconHelper.CreateIconHandleFromBitmapFrame(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame)
>     at MS.Internal.AppModel.IconHelper.CreateIconHandleFromImageSource(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource, System.Windows.Size)
>     at MS.Internal.AppModel.IconHelper.GetIconHandlesFromImageSource(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource, IconHandle ByRef, IconHandle ByRef)
>     at System.Windows.Window.UpdateIcon()
>     at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double, Double, Double, Double)
>     at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean)
>     at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>     at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>     at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>     at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>     at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>     at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>     at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
>     at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
>     at ClientLauncher.App.Main()

Then you might be running into a bug like [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/321285/wpf-application-fails-if-window-icon-is-a-vista-ico-file?iframe=true&width=80%&height=80%), except for it could happen on newer OS, like Windows 10. Some of our clients have this kind of crashes on Windows 10 machines.

The solution is to simplify the icon file, don't let it contain frames larger than 64*64, or simply use a PNG for window icon instead. That being said, high resolution icons could still be used as app icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (not elegant, but it works)
In the loaded event for the window:

```
Private Sub TileLayout_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Me.winTileLayout.Icon = Bitmap2BitmapSource(My.Resources.VisualizerIcon.ToBitmap)
End Sub
```

And the helper function:

```
Public Shared Function Bitmap2BitmapSource(bmp As System.Drawing.Bitmap) As BitmapSource
    Dim retval As BitmapSource = Nothing
    Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = bmp.GetHbitmap()
    Try
        retval = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())
    Catch ex As Win32Exception
        retval = Nothing
    Finally
        DeleteObject(hBitmap)
    End Try
    Return retval
End Function
```

The DeleteObject code:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function DeleteObject(hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```